# manage several connections with the same traffic light - SUMO

Tags: sumo, network-traffic, traffic-simulation

I'm new to SUMO, so my question/problem could be trivial, maybe I didn't search enough.

This is my problem :

I have a network that I edited through Netedit and I want to implement a certain traffic light (TL) phase in an [intersection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLvFQ.jpg)

On an edge, there is two lane : bus lane and car lane. There are 3 possible directions (straight for the buses, straight and right for the cars) so Netedit creates (as I understand) 3 different TL. However, the TL phase(or sequence, it depends on how you name it) is the same. It means that, in reality, the two TL in this road give the same information of green and red, no difference between buses and cars.

Since the TL phase is given to me, I need the same amount of TL in the simulation and in the reality in order to implement it almost as a "copy - paste".

So I have a couple of questions :

-is it possible to join several TL as one in order to manage several connections/directions with the same TL ?
The idea behind this is : is it possible to differentiate connections/direction from TL in netedit ?

-What could be another approach to deal with my problem ?

This the [edge with the TL index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAaGe.jpg), it could be useful to understand each other.

Thank you for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

I think the concept you are refering to is called [signal groups](https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Simulation/Traffic_Lights.html#defining_signal_groups) in SUMO. You can open up netedit and group the connections you would like to join into a group by choosing "group signals".